# SQL query for ids, who never show a special combination

Tags: sql, kylin

I have 2 tables like

```
id_a | id_b
-----------
01   | 011
01   | 012
02   | 021
02   | 022
```

and

```
id_b |  cl   | ds
------------------
011  | F9.00 | G
012  | F3.00 | G
021  | F9.00 | P
022  | G7.50 | G
```

the tables are joined on id_b.
Now I want to know every Id_a where there is no combination of `F9.00 | G`. So in this case, my desired result is `02`. Even though, the row `01 | 012 | F3.00 | G` does not match the `F9.00 | G` requirement, I dont want to have `01` as an result, because there is the combination `01 |011 | F9.00 | G` with `01` as `id_a`.

Cant think of an easy query at the moment. Maybe some of you have an idea.

Regards, Søren

Comment: what RDBMS? mySQL, SQL SERVER else?  and what have you tried?  this seems like a straight forward exists, not in, or left join where null..

Comment: Specify the expected result (as a table, like the ones you already have.)

Comment: its in kylin, which uses calcite as queryengine. the result should be just one column with the id_a's on the UI

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select t1.id_a
from t1
  join t2 on t1.id_b = t2.id_b
where (t2.cl, t2.ds) <> ('F9.00', 'G')
group by t1.id_a
having count(*) = (select count(*) 
                   from t1 as t3
                   where t3.id_a = t1.id_a);
```

This gets the rows where no combination of `'F9.00', 'G'` exists and only those where the resulting row count for that is the same as the total rowcount for that `id_a`.

---

Edit, after the platform was specified:

The above is ANSI SQL - I don't know if kylin supports ANSI SQL. If `where (t2.cl, t2.ds) <> ('F9.00', 'G')` doesn't work, you need to use `where t2.cl <> 'F9.00' and t2.ds <> 'G'`

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_a
from table1
except
select t1.id_a
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id_b=t2.id_b
where t2.c1 = F9.00
and t2.ds = G
```

This code will grab the IDs you don't want at the bottom, all the IDs at the top, and then it will exclude them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT` on columns c1 and ds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_a
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
ON T1.id_b = T2.id_b
WHERE id_a NOT IN
(SELECT id_a
 FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
 ON T1.id_b = T2.id_b
 WHERE CONCAT(c1, ds) = 'F9.00G')
```